# accessing Root shell

Tags: security, root

I'm able to access the root shell via the following commands:

`sudo -i`  `sudo su` (after providing the user password)
or `su` (after providing the root password)

What is the difference between them? I notice that a user with root privileges can access the root account!

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully `su` to root it means that you know the password, which means that you *are* root. If you can `sudo -i` then you *have* privileges -- specifically, your account has been added to the `adm` group, making it an administrator.